# JavaScript inline split(',').splice()

Tags: javascript, array-splice

I'm trying to perform an inline split() then splice(), and it's not working.

```
var newValue = "61471acddbbfef00961374b5ae961943,fafd1e39db3fa20084cc74b5ae961914";
var test = (newValue.toString().split(',')).splice(0,1,'test');
console.log(test);
```

Output is:
**Array ["61471acddbbfef00961374b5ae961943"]**

But I'm expecting:
**Array ["test","61471acddbbfef00961374b5ae961943"]**

Now, if I do this:

```
var test = newValue.toString().split(',');
test.splice(0,1,'test');
console.log(test);
```

I get what I'm looking for:
**Array ["test","61471acddbbfef00961374b5ae961943"]**

Why can't I make it all inline?: **(newValue.toString().split(',')).splice(0,1,'test');**

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)? It modifies the array in place and returns the removed elements.

Comment: `.toString()` is superfluous. `newValue` is already a string, calling `.toString()` on it is a no-op.

Comment: The second code snippet does not display `["test","61471acddbbfef00961374b5ae961943"]`. `Array.splice(0, 1, 'test')` removes `1` item starting at position `0` and puts `'test'` instead of the removed item(s). The result of `test.splice(0,1,'test')` is ['test', 'fafd1e39db3fa20084cc74b5ae961914']`.

Comment: @axiac, you're absolutely right..  "Return value: An array containing the deleted elements."... I was so caught up in what I assumed it returned I didn't read the documentation in full.  Totally my mistake.  Thank you for pointing it out and it all makes sense to me now why it wasn't giving me the result I was looking for... <smh>

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need it as an oneliner, you can do it with `concat` and `slice`.

```js
var str = "a,b,c";
var test = ['test'].concat(str.split(',').slice(0, 1));

console.log(test);
// output: [ "test", "a" ]
```